# Is there a way to store a function and it's parameters in a variable to call later?

Tags: c#, delegates

In C#, I want to do something like this.

```
var fn = // set it to the function and parameters it'll use

fn();
```

In a hypothetical example, say I wanted to return a function with all of the parameters it needed to execute, I just wanted to execute it from somewhere else.

Comment: var fn = () => SomeFunction(arg1, arg2);

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what is wrong with my question? I'd like to fix it if it's not clear what I'm asking.

Comment: they almost never do....

Comment: @MongZhu Yah. I have no idea what's wrong with the question. It was answered and commented on within a couple of minutes, so it must've been clear what I was asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an `Action` delegate invoking the function with the parameters:

```
var fn = () => OtherFunction(param1, param2);
```

If parameters can change before `fn` being invoked you can make a copy of the parameters assigning them to new variables if are by value or implementing some `Clone` mechanism if are by reference:

```
var value1 = param1;  // In case of value types.
var value2 = param2;  // In case of value types.
var fn = () => OtherFunction(value1, value2);
```

Then invoke the `fn` action later:

```
fn();
```

Comment: Just be careful, if you change the value of `param1` or `pram2` before calling `fn()` [it will use the updated value, not the value at the time the delegate was created](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt/2008/03/01/understanding-variable-capturing-in-c/).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Yes, it's true, it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: I've actually done this before and I couldn't for the life of me remember. Chalking this up to after 4:00 on a Friday. Thanks!